# Sets with empty interior

Tags: general-topology

I search for  a $T_1$ crowded topological space $X$ which is not a countable union of co-dense sets. Can you give an example of such spaces?

Comment: Why don't the reals work?

Comment: Consider the set of rationals and the set of irrationals, both of them have empty interiors  and the union of them is $ R$.

Comment: So there cannot be a dense set with dense complement. So it must be an irresolvable space.

Comment: Both the rationals and irrationals are co-dense ( their complement is dense). Or how do you define co-dense?

Comment: Dear Henno;
Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{N}$ in the co-countable topology.

This $T_1$ and crowded trivially.

$D$ is dense in (assuming a non-countable set) the co-countable topology iff it is uncountable.

So $A$ is co-dense, iff it has uncountable complement.

So $X = \cup_n \mathbb{R} \times \{n\}$ is a crowded T_1 space which is a countable union of co-dense sets.

Comment: We could have used the reals in the co-countable topology and the positive and negative numbers as two co-dense sets.